# Ringlead is preventing creation of Leads, Contacts and Accounts

Tags: account, contact, leads

I just got a new job with a company that use Ringlead. One symptom that I am seeing today is that leads, contacts and accounts cannot be created. I don't know why but its weird:
If I or anyone else tries to create from the UI it fails.
If I or anyone loads a list it works.
If I login as someone else it works (though it did fail one time)

I pushed a new field to Contacts and Leads from dev to full and then from full to production on the 24th. Tested in Full without an issue both then and today.

I used logging but all I see are successes.

Has anyone seen this issue and know what might be occurring?

Comment: Not familiar with that particular package, what are the errors you're getting when it fails to create?

Comment: None... I just get an empty screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...

I went in yesterday to add better security to the org and checked the "Lock Sessions to IP address" and that is what broke it.

I changed it back, logged out and then back in and now Leads, Contacts and Accounts work as expected.

Comment: I use Ringleads as well! That information helps. Thanks for posting !